# How to do uppercase with velocity

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, velocity

I'm creating a template in intellij IDEA and I need to have a method that will be called

```
fun setSomething()
```

but currently my template writes it like this

```
fun setsomething()
```

How can I set this method to have camelcase and Something with first letter in uppercase ?

```
fun set$List_Name(${List_Name}: List<${Model_Class}>){
    this.${List_Name}.clear()
    this.${List_Name}.addAll(${List_Name})
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

here $List_name needs to be uppercase first letter

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing

```
fun set$List_Name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()$List_Name.substring(1)(${List_Name}: List<${Model_Class}>){
    this.${List_Name}.clear()
    this.${List_Name}.addAll(${List_Name})
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```